# Angular: How to catch Http Status Code of a failed http.get() method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I have an http.get() method which tries to query a backend API. Given an Id in Frontend, enable a property in the database (this is handled by the backend)
I implemented the http method this way:

home.ts

```
this.service.getZ(id).subscribe((event:any)=>console.log(event))
```

service.ts

```
 getz(id):
    return http.get('url'+id,{reportProgress: true,
   responseType: 'text'
}).
```

Now I need to catch what http status code the backend is sending as I need this status code (like http 200, http 500) to enable another button in the frontend.
But for some reason I am just not able to capture the http status in the 'event' variable in the home.ts (as shown above).
In console, i get this message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djpNZ.png)

But I am just enable to extract the http status code into a variable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the handler is only invoke call succeeds. For error there is one more callback. so change your code to :-

```
this.service.getZ(id).subscribe(
   (event:any)=>console.log(event),
   (err) => console.log(err.statusCode)
)
```